# LC Parallel resonance induction heater

Tags: power, parallel, resonance, efficiency, induction-heater

Consider parallel LC resonance induction circuit with solid iron workpiece, inserted in the inductor. Is it possible to obtain more heat power output from the heated solid iron workpiece in the inductor,
compared to the electrical power consumed in an LC parallel resonance induction circuit?

Is it possible as a result,  the electrical power input to LC circuit to be, for example, 100 watts, the heat power generated from the the heated solid iron workpiece to be higher, say 200 watts or more, depending on the efficiency of the system and the characteristics of the load?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Quite the opposite, actually; a parallel resonant LC circuit has infinite impedance; the inductor and capacitor are simply exchanging energy. If you add resistance to change electrical power to thermal energy, you are creating a resistive heater which is 100% efficient.  If you introduce eddy current losses into the inductor core to extract heat, you've just made an inductively powered resistive heater with power factor correction

Answer (score 0):

NO.
The law of energy conservation prohibits this.

In fact, when you put lossy core into inductor, your LC circuit becomes LCR circuit, when R is an induction loss, with different resonant curve and different relationship between I_in and I_L.

LC circuit in inductors is put for efficienty - you need high inductor I_L current to make high magnetic field and high induction currents in lossy core.
With C you can get it with much less I_in correspoinding to I_L. But addition of R_loss decrease I_L/I_in significantly.

Comment: Lets say (Parallel LC resonance) I prepare the inductor and the workpiece first , then i add capacitors in parallel until I reach resonance state, so that the input current become very low (Very high ratio of I_L/I_in ). I still would not be able to achieve this low input current (Very high ratio of I_L/I_in ), so there is COP>1 ?

Comment: Lets say (Parallel LC resonance), First I prepare the inductor and the workpiece  , then i switch capacitors in parallel until I reach resonance state, so that the input current become very low (Very high ratio of I_L/I_in ). I still would not be able to achieve this low input current (Very high ratio of I_L/I_in ), so there is COP>1 ?

Comment: yesterday: if you add additional load like lossy core, the quality factor of the LC circuit drops abruptly and ratio I_L/I_in drops too
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit#Other_configurations

Comment: So it is not possible to achieve high "Q" in parallel resonance configuration if I first prepare the inductor with solid iron core (the inductor with the iron core will still have some L - inductance value), and then to switch capacitors in parallel until i reach parallel resonance state with high "Q" value?

Comment: Inductor Current/Input Current.

Comment: It is not possible to achieve high "Q" in lossy circuit.